# Testing a function which is wrapped inside a setTime out function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having some issues testing a function which is wrapped inside a setTimeout function.
Basically, what I want to test is the setUpdate method gets called with a false parameter.

```
const UpdateContainer: FunctionComponent<UpdateProps> = ({
  showUpdate,
  showError,
  dateOfBirth,
}) => {
  
  const [isEditable, setIsEditable] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState<boolean>(true);
 

  


  const onCancel = function async() {
    setIsEditable(false);
    setIsEditing(false);
    setTimeout(()=> {
     ** /*Wants to check if this method is invoked with a false param*/**
      showUpdate(false);
    },600);
  };

  const initialValues: UpdateValues = {
    birth_date: dateOfBirth,
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    
  });

  return (
    <Card
      cancelText={t('cancel')}
      confirmText={t('confirm')}
      isEditable={isEditable}
      isEditing={isEditing}
      setIsEditable={setIsEditable}
      setIsEditing={setIsEditing}
      onCancel={() => onCancel()}
    >
     
     
      <CardItem
        body={
          <Input
            disabled
            id="dateOfBirthUpdate"
            textTransform="none"
            type="text"
            value={moment(new Date(formik.values.birth_date ? formik.values.birth_date : '')).format('ll')}
          />
        }
      />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

I have tried following the jest docs, but for some reason the test is unable to detect the invoke of setUpdate function

This is what I have tried so far

```
``
  it('on Clicking Cancel inside a tool tip it sets the show update to false', async () => {
    tree(props)
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    act(()=>{
      jest.runAllTimers()
    })
    const cancelButton = screen.getByText('common:cancel');
    expect(cancelButton).not.toBeNull();
    userEvent.click(cancelButton);
    const toolTipCancel= screen.getByText('common:cancelEditTooltip.cancelButtonText')
    userEvent.click(toolTipCancel);
    await expect(props.showUpdate).toBeCalledWith(false)  
  });

`
```

`

Comment: There is no `setUpdate` function in your code

Answer (score 0):

1. In the test, before passing the props in tree(props), try setting the props.showUpdate = jest.fn()
2. wrap the last assertion in a waitFor() like below:

```js
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(props.showUpdate).toBeCalledWith(false)
})
```